# Angular controller not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am starting an O'Reilly book, AngularJS and the first example is as follows. On my end the "{{greeting.text}}" is showing up as that inside of being replaced with hello. I have the angular linked properly, and when I put it into jsFiddle it doesn't work as well, unless I change onLoad to no wrap- then it works.

I am using Webstorm on mac and I'm thinking my problem may be in there, but can't find anything that has fixed it.

Thank you for helping what is probably a simple solution.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head lang="en">
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src ="controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="HelloController">
        <p>{{greeting.text}}, World</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
function HelloController($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello'};
}
```

Comment: use angular 1.2 and it will work. 1.3 is a little different but since you're learning off the book, you might as well use the more compatible version.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something might be wrong with the way you are including angular. The following code works fine for me

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head lang="en">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src ="controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="HelloController">
        <p>{{greeting.text}}, World</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

controllers.js:

```
function HelloController($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello'};
}
```

Open up your index.html in chrome and press Command + Option + J and when the developer tools open up, head to the network tab, refresh the page and see if you are loading your angular.js script correctly - if not, that is the issue.

Comment: Loaded from the CDN and it works perfect. Should have checked that first. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Which angular version you use?
Mine is 1.3

```
angular.module('HelloApp', [])
  .controller('HelloController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello'};
}
```